# Proving an error bound for solving a linear system with iterative method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose I have a system $Ax = b$, and I have a pseudoinverse for $A$, namely $Q$, where:

$\| I - Q^{-1}A \| = \delta < 1$

for some induced matrix norm.

My question is, how do I show this error bound for $x$ as a function of the iterates $x^{(k)}$?

$ \| x^{(k)} - x \| \le \frac{\delta}{1 - \delta} \| x^{(k)} - x^{(k-1)}\|$

I have tried starting with the triangle inequality of the norm:

$\| x^{(k-1)} - x \|$

$\| x^{(k-1)} - x^{(k)} + x^{(k)} - x \|$

$\le \| x^{(k-1)} - x^{(k)} \| + \| x^{(k)} - x \|$

And working backward from the result thus:

$(1 - \delta) \| x^{(k)} - x \| \le \delta \| x^{(k)} - x^{(k-1)}\|$

$\iff (1 - \| (I - Q^{-1}A) \|) \| x^{(k)} - x \| \le \| (I - Q^{-1}A) \|  \| x^{(k)} - x^{(k-1)}\|$

$\iff \| x^{(k)} - x \| - \| x^{(k)} - x \| \| (I - Q^{-1}A) \|  \le \| (I - Q^{-1}A) \|  \| x^{(k)} - x^{(k-1)}\|$

$\iff \| x^{(k)} - x \| \le \| (I - Q^{-1}A) \| (\| x^{(k)} - x \| + \| x^{(k)} - x^{(k-1)}\|)$

$\iff \| x^{(k)} - x \| \le \| x^{(k)} - x \| + \| x^{(k)} - x^{(k-1)}\|$

Comment: If $x_{k+1} = (I - Q^{-1}A)x_k$, then looking at the proof of the Banach fixed point theorem may be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $x-x_k=(I-Q^{-1}A)(x-x_{k-1})$, so
$$
\|x-x_k\|\leq\delta\|x-x_{k-1}\|=\delta\|(x-x_k)+(x_k-x_{k-1})\|
\leq\delta\|x-x_k\|+\delta\|x_k-x_{k-1}\|.
$$
Now just move the first term on the right hand side left and divide by $1-\delta$.

Comment: Thank you so much!